# UINavigationBar, back button, and dismissModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, modalviewcontroller

I have an app that is navigation based, so all views default to have a top nav bar. I have reached a page where a back button is not displayed by default for whatever reason and I was required to add one programatically. Unfortunately, the back button does not dismiss the modal view as expected.

I load the view in question through:

```
-(IBAction) linkPress:(id)sender
{
    potentialUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:((Button*)sender).emailContent];

    webViewInst = [[WebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView" bundle:nil url:potentialUrl];

    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"]){
        [self presentModalViewController:webViewInst animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewInst animated:YES];
    }    
}
```

I add the back button through:

```
UIBarButtonItem *MKbackBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButton:)]; 
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:MKbackBtn];
```

And the action that the back button should take to remove the view and return to the previous view:

```
-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController* parent = [self parentViewController];
    if(parent==nil) {
        parent = [self presentingViewController];
    }
    [parent dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If another set of eyes could go over these bits of code and try to discern what mistake I have made, that would be greatly appreciated! I am more than willing to provide more information/code as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` but based on your code above there's a chance that it's not presented as modal and is instead pushed onto the navStack, in which case `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` wouldn't actually dismiss it. Instead you would need to do `popViewController` etc. You should be casing around the presentation means. Can you confirm that this isn't part of the problem?

Also, off the top of my head I think you would call `[self dismissModalViewController...]` rather than `parent`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I am unable to use `popViewController`. How would I confirm that I am not doing what you suggest the problem might be? I think I am misunderstanding you somewhere along the lines there.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I was able to use `popviewController` to perform the function I wanted, I was just mistyping a small portion of it which prevented the autofill. Furthermore, why was the view pushed onto the navStack rather than as a ModalViewController?

Comment: Awesome! I was just going to say that I believe you can check the presentation style of self and use that as a condition to choose your dismissal method...basically, in your first block of code you're using modal for ipad but navstack for iphone. I'm guessing you were testing on the phone which meant that the dismissModal command wasn't working because the viewController wasn't presented modally, no?

Comment: Indeed, if I had created the original code for this app, I would have made the ipad and iphone function the same way (both using a modal view). You are completely correct, the ipad was functioning correctly whereas the iphone was not. My confusion arose due to the fact that the way I have presented views and dismissed them up to this point has been (more or less) identical to the above code (and has worked flawlessly). In any case, it functions (but I wish I had more time to actually understand the code). Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a view controller modally does not include it in the navigation controller's stack.  You have to provide your own UI mechanism to dismiss the modal view.  It looks to me like your solution to dismiss the modal view controller should mostly work--although I think all you need is this one line in `backButton:`:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: NOTE: I'm assuming the `backButton:` handler is only used for your modal view controller--for your view controllers in the UINavigationController stack you should stick to the standard back button behavior.  Unless you really want to use your own back button, in which case stick with your implementation but call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on self, not the parent.

Comment: Using the code `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` did not remove the view. As far as the standard back button behavior, there is no back button present on the view. I would much rather use the standard back button, but due to it's disappearance, I had to implement my own back button.